# How to resolve a hostname conditionally on the connected network?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, hosts, netctl

I have a small home server and I'd like programs on my laptop to be able to access it from both LAN and WAN. I think that the cleanest way to achieve this is to define a custom hostname and resolve it differently based on the network it's connected to.

In other words, is it possible to resolve hostname *X* as ip address *A* if connected to network *Foo*, and as ip address *B* otherwise?

I'm using Arch Linux and `netctl` as my network manager. I assume the way to achieve what I want is to set up hooks in the network profile for *Foo* to somehow change the hosts file, but I'm not sure on how to do the latter.

Of course, I'd like to hear about better solutions, too.

Comment: Search for "split DNS" or "split-horizon DNS".

Comment: @SatoKatsura, thanks for putting me on the right track. For various reasons I can't set up a DNS server for the whole LAN, but I found a nice compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with `dnsmasq`. Following the example in the question, here's what I did after setting up `dnsmasq` to act as a DNS cache on my laptop:

1. Create a directory `/etc/hosts.d`
2. Put the following scripts in `/etc/netctl/X/` and make them executable

```bsh
 #!/bin/sh
 # /etc/netctl/X/X_local.sh
 echo 'A X' > /etc/hosts.d/X
 chmod 744 /etc/hosts.d/X
```

```bsh
 #!/bin/sh
 # /etc/netctl/X/X_remote.sh
 echo 'B X' > /etc/hosts.d/X
 chmod 744 /etc/hosts.d/X
```

3. Add the following lines to the network profile `/etc/netctl/Foo`

```bsh
 ExecUpPost=/etc/netctl/X/X_local.sh
 ExecDownPre=/etc/netctl/X/X_remote.sh
```

4. Append `addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.d` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

This works because the `addn-hosts` option instructs `dnsmasq` to look in the `/etc/hosts.d` directory for additional hostname associations.